# How to implement unnamed semaphore and where is it stored? Is it same as unnamed pipe implementation?

Tags: c, semaphore

```
int sem_init(sem_t *sem, int pshared, unsigned int value);
```

What is the sem pointer in this prototype?
What to give as a pointer?
What is pshared and how to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

> where is it stored?

That's up to you. That's why you pass it a pointer instead of it returning one to you.

> What is the sem pointer in this prototype?

The address where it's going to initialize the semaphore at.

> What to give as a pointer?

Somewhere that you allocated `sizeof(sem_t)` bytes that it can use, and that will be accessible by all threads/processes that you want to use the semaphore.

> What is pshared and how to implement it?

Set it to 1 if you're going to share the semaphore between processes, or to 0 if you're not.